# Find area of overlapping rectangles in Python / OpenCV with a raw list of points

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, coordinates

I have the coordinates `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` of a rectangle and a list of other coordinates for other rectangles.

I want to compare the value of the one I already have over with the others to see if they overlap more than `50%` of the original rectangle.

I checked other resources but still, I could get my head around it:

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151309/check-if-two-rectangles-overlap
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31352/overlapping-rectangles

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's first simplify your problem to a single dimension:

You have an interval `A = [a0, a1]` and want to find out how much does another interval `B = [b0, b1]` intersects with it. I will represent `A` with `=` and `B` with `-`.

There are 6 possible scenarios:

- `A` contains `B`, `intersection = b1 - b0`

  ```
  a0  b0  b1  a1
  ==============
      ------
  ```
- `B` contains `A`, `intersection = a1 - a0`

  ```
  b0  a0  a1  b1
      ======
  --------------
  ```
- `B` intersects `A` from the left, `intersection = b1 - a0`

  ```
  b0  a0  b1  a1
      ==========
  ----------
  ```
- `B` intersects `A` from the right, `intersection = a1 - b0`

  ```
  a0  b0  a1  b1
  ==========
      ----------
  ```
- `B` is to the left of `A`, `intersection = 0`

  ```
  b0  b1  a0  a1
          ======
  ------
  ```
- `B` is to the right of `A`, `intersection = 0`

  ```
  a0  a1  b0  b1
  ======
          ------
  ```

Based on that, we can define a function that, given two intervals `A = [a0, a1]` and `B = [b0, b1]`, returns how much they intersect:

```
def calculateIntersection(a0, a1, b0, b1):
    if a0 >= b0 and a1 <= b1: # Contained
        intersection = a1 - a0
    elif a0 < b0 and a1 > b1: # Contains
        intersection = b1 - b0
    elif a0 < b0 and a1 > b0: # Intersects right
        intersection = a1 - b0
    elif a1 > b1 and a0 < b1: # Intersects left
        intersection = b1 - a0
    else: # No intersection (either side)
        intersection = 0

    return intersection
```

That's pretty much everything you need. To find out how much do two rectangles intersect, you just need to execute this function on both the `X` and the `Y` axis and multiply those amounts to get the intersecting area:

```
# The rectangle against which you are going to test the rest and its area:
X0, Y0, X1, Y1, = [0, 0, 10, 10]
AREA = float((X1 - X0) * (Y1 - Y0))

# Rectangles to check
rectangles = [[15, 0, 20, 10], [0, 15, 10, 20], [0, 0, 5, 5], [0, 0, 5, 10], [0, 5, 10, 100], [0, 0, 100, 100]]

# Intersecting rectangles:
intersecting = []

for x0, y0, x1, y1 in rectangles:       
    width = calculateIntersection(x0, x1, X0, X1)        
    height = calculateIntersection(y0, y1, Y0, Y1)        
    area = width * height
    percent = area / AREA

    if (percent >= 0.5):
        intersecting.append([x0, y0, x1, y1])
```

The result will be:

- `[15, 0, 20, 10]` does not intersect in the X-axis, so `width = 0`.
- `[0, 15, 10, 20]` does not intersect in the Y-axis, so `height = 0`.
- `[0, 0, 5, 5]` intersects only `25%`.
- `[0, 0, 5, 10]` intersects `50%` and will be added to `intersecting`.
- `[0, 5, 10, 100]` intersects `50%` and will be added to `intersecting`.
- `[0, 0, 100, 100]` intersects `100%` and will be added to `intersecting`.

Answer (score 0):

The overlap area is the product of the overlap width and the overlap height.

To find the width overlap of the rectangles `XY` and `xy`, take the rightmost of the left edges and the leftmost of the right edges. Numerically, `max(X1, x1)` and `min(X2, x2)`. Thus the overlap width is `min(X2, x2) - max(X1, x1)`. If this is negative, there is no overlap at all. Repeat for the height.

Thus, the area of overlap can be expressed with a single formula:

```
max(0, min(X2, x2) - max(X1, x1)) . max(0, min(Y2, y2) - max(Y1, y1))
```

[Total cost: six comparisons, two subtractions, one product (plus one comparison to the target area).]

As a micro-optimization, you can conclude "no" immediately if

```
min(X2, x2) - max(X1, x1) < 50% (X2 - X1)
```

[With some probability, the cost is reduced to three comparisons and one subtraction.]